# calling version of is_const<> but for variables instead of types, in one line

Tags: c++, struct, type-traits, member-variables, scope-resolution-operator

Hi I am learning c++ and I read about type traits such as is_const.
is_const can be called in one line like,

```
cout << is_const<double>::value << endl;
```

I made my own version of is_const but to test if a variable is const, and it can be used like this,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
  struct check_const {
    check_const(const T *x): val(std::true_type{})
    { }
    check_const(T *x) : val(std::false_type{})
    { }
    bool val;
};

int main() 
{
   const double pi= 3.14;
   check_const<double> r(&pi);
   cout <<  r.val << endl;    // returns 1
   double x= 2.7;
   check_const<double> s(&x);
   cout << s.val << endl;    // returns 0
   return(0);
}
```

I would like to call check_const in one line as well, but the compiler keeps giving me errors like

```
"typename not allowed"
```

when I try calling it like

```
cout << check_const<double> t(&pi)::val << endl;
```

How can I change check_const, so it can be called in one line?

Comment: Do you know how to use `decltype()`?

Comment: please dont paraphrase errors "like "typename not allowed"", but include error message in the question

Comment: how do I include error messages?

Comment: you dont need type traits to check if a variable is const or not. All you need is a function iwth a const and a non-const overload. Actually you already use that in your code

Comment: you copy them and paste them into your question

Comment: @idclev I realize it is not useful, I'm just doing it for fun

Comment: @rafix07 that worked! Is there a name for that, where can i read why that works?

Comment: @Sam I do not know declaretype(), but I will read about it, how would you use it here though?

Comment: @betafractal Your code works perfectly. All you needed was a semicolon on line 18

Comment: I see now if I call it without assigning to an object, it works. Thank you! I will read about decltype() and try to implement with that @Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just using a slightly wrong syntax here:

```
cout << check_const<double> t(&pi)::val << endl;
```

Instead use

```
cout << check_const<double>(&pi).val << endl;
```

`check_const<double> t(&pi)` is the syntax for the definition of a named variable, but you cannot have declarations/definitions inside an expression.

`check_const<double>(&pi)` is the syntax to create an unnamed temporary, which can be done in expressions.

Then you need `.` instead of `::`, because `val` is a non-static member of `check_const`.

Starting with C++17 you could also write:

```
cout << check_const(&pi).val << endl;
```

and have the template argument be deduced for you.

---

All of this can be simplified though, as you aren't really using the class. You can just use the constructors as free functions:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool check_const(const T *x) noexcept { return true; }

template<typename T>
constexpr bool check_const(T *x) noexcept { return false; }
```

(The `constexpr` makes it possible to use the functions in constant expressions, but is otherwise not required. Similarly `noexcept` is just an indicator that the function doesn't throw exceptions, but is otherwise not required.)

This can be used more easily as

```
cout << check_const(&pi) << endl;
```

Also, instead of pointers, use references:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool check_const(const T &x) noexcept { return true; }

template<typename T>
constexpr bool check_const(T &x) noexcept { return false; }
```

and you can write

```
cout << check_const(pi) << endl;
```